# Login form with Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

i have a problem when i want to login , i get always that the password and email are not corrects even if they are correct ..

this is the controller :

```
 public function authentification (Request $request) 
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [

        'email' => 'required',
        'mdp'=> 'required'
    ]);

    $logmedecin=doc::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() ;
    $rdv=rendezvous::get(); 

    foreach ($logmedecin as $log ) 
    {
    if (( $lo->Login== 'email') && ($log->Password=='mdp' ))
     {
    return view ('/Welcome',['med'=>$log] ,['pat'=>$rdv] );
    }

}
    return  ("Password or mail not correct") ; 
}


    }
```

And this is the form :

```
<form  class="form-signin" method="post" action="{{route('aziz')}}"> 
    @csrf  

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder=" mail" data-rule="email" autofocus="" /> </br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="mdp" placeholder="password" data-rule="required"/>      
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> Se connecter </button> <br>
     <center> <a href="inscription"> Inscrivez-vous </a>  </center> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a typo in your code. Change `$lo->Login` to `$log->Login`

```php
foreach ($logmedecin as $log ) 
{
    if (( $log->Login== 'email') && ($log->Password=='mdp' ))
    {
        return view ('/Welcome',['med'=>$log] ,['pat'=>$rdv] );
    }
}
```

And I'm guessing you don't want to be checking whether there exists a `doc` with `Login == "email"` and `Password == "mdp"`. You'll want to grab the relevant values from the user's request:

```php
foreach ($logmedecin as $log ) 
{
    if (( $log->Login== $request->input('email') ) && ( $log->Password== $request->input('mdp') ))
    {
        return view ('/Welcome',['med'=>$log] ,['pat'=>$rdv] );
    }
}
```